# How to directly run MeteorJs project using netbeans? Just by pressing green button

Tags: meteor, netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-8

How to directly run MeteorJs(Node) project using netbeans? Just by pressing the green button.
Please tell me the configuration of Meteorjs in netbeans.